# php built-in server - How to set APPLICATION_ENV to $_SERVER

Tags: php, zend-framework2, php-builtin-server

I using Zend Framework 2 and PHP built-in server.

Zend documentation says:

> Optionally, when using Apache, you can use the APPLICATION_ENV setting
>   in your VirtualHost to let PHP output all its errors to the browser.
>   This can be useful during the development of your application.

I want to be able to see all errors when I run the "php-built-in-server" on my machine.

But if I set `$_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] = 'development'` at the beginning in `index.php` it can be difficult to work with public (dev) GIT remote and (deployment) private remote. Everytime when I have to commit something I have to change the `$_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV']` for each environment - in each commit.

Is there a way to set a `$_SERVER[]` variable without affecting the actual code?

Comment: Is there anyway you can include this call in an external file, then have git ignore it when you commit/vice-versa?

Comment: @HunterFrazier - thanks it's good idea. I will try to do something like this without affecting Zend functionality.

Comment: @Devon - Yes I have seen this question - it's about apache and `.htaccess`. PHP built-in server not supporting `.htaccess`

Comment: My fault, I misunderstood your question, removed it.

Comment: Consult this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784116/setting-environment-variables-with-the-built-in-php-web-server