# How to use the PHP built-in server with Windows Authentication (NTLM) to fill $_SERVER["LOGON_USER"]?

Tags: php, php-builtin-server, ntlm-authentication

I have scripts that use the `$_SERVER["LOGON_USER"]` which is obtained on my servers through IIS authentication settings. I want this same variable to contain my `domain\username` when running locally, or at least to have a way to set it when I fire up the PHP built-in server on localhost.

How can I configure PHP on my machine to obtain and fill this variable the same way it does when running through IIS?

<sub>PS: I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784116/setting-environment-variables-with-the-built-in-php-web-server), but the answer addresses `$_ENV`, not `$_SERVER`.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround, if anyone has a better/proper solution (i.e. enabling NTLM), please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

I was able to fill that variable using a router script. According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), this script is run at the start of each HTTP request, so I use it to set this variable when running locally.

Also in my case, my environment had these two variables set, `USERDOMAIN` and `USERNAME`, so I used them to form the `LOGON_USER` server variable.

**routerCredentials.php**

```php
<?php
$_SERVER["LOGON_USER"] = getenv("USERDOMAIN") . "\\" . getenv("USERNAME");
return false; // serve the requested resource as-is.
```

To use it, you just have to point to that file when you start the PHP built-in server:

```
php -S localhost:8000 "c:\somepath\routerCredentials.php"
```